# Django - Search matches with all objects - even if they don't actually match

Tags: django, postgresql, full-text-search

This is the model that has to be searched:

```
class BlockQuote(models.Model):
    debate = models.ForeignKey(Debate, related_name='quotes')
    speaker = models.ForeignKey(Speaker, related_name='quotes')
    text = models.TextField()
```

I have around a thousand instances on the database on my laptop (with around 50000 on the production server)

I am creating a 'manage.py' function that will search through the database and returns all 'BlockQuote' objects whose textfield contains the keyword.

I am doing this with the Django's (1.11)  Postgres search options in order to use the 'rank' attribute, which sounds like something that would come in handy. [I used the official Django fulltext-search documentation for the code below](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/postgres/search/)

Yet when I run this code, it matches with all objects, regardless if  BlockQuote.text actually contains the queryfield.

```
def handle(self, *args, **options):
    vector = SearchVector('text')
    query = options['query'][0]
    Search_Instance = Search_Instance.objects.create(query=query)
    set = BlockQuote.objects.annotate(rank=SearchRank(vector, query)).order_by('-rank')

    for result in set:
        match = QueryMatch.objects.create(quote=result, query=Search_Instance)
        match.save()
```

Does anyone have an idea of what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Not very familiar with rank search myself, but after reading the docs a bit, I feel like I either need more code or have to ask: Is SearchQuery supposed to be initialized via `objects.create(query=query)` instead of just `SearchQuery(query)` (which is how it's used in the docs and other random tutorials I found, and without the `query=` too), maybe the issue is that initialization(?)

Comment: Apologies for the confusion, the SearchQuery is a separate database object, that I use to link all results to the relevant search. The name is to close to the django method though - so I've changed the name in the example (and in my code)

Thanks for your response!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see you actually filtering ever.

```
BlockQuote.objects.annotate(...).filter(rank__gte=0.5)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, I've added your code to my code 
set = BlockQuote.objects.annotate(rank=SearchRank(vector, query)).filter(rank__gte=0.5).order_by('-rank')

There is some improvement in that it no longer matches with all objects in the database. But its currently matching with nothing. Even when I am searching for a word that I know is in the text of an object.

Comment: Yeah, you'll need to mess around with the ranking and what things are being rated. I suggest printing out the values of it unfiltered with a few terms and see what you want and where the cutoff should be.